# Updating an iframe, history and URL. Then making it work with back button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser-history

I'm having problems getting URL to update when hitting the back button on the browser (I'm on testing on Firefox). After updating the "src" property of the iframe I use `replaceState` to update the history. If I hit the back button after this the iframe will go back to the previous page but the URL does not update to reflect this.

```
function updateURLBar(urlInfo) {
    var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
    document.getElementById("iframeContent").src = urlInfo[1];
    window.history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 2", urlInfo[0]);
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way or am I just missing something. Thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not sure I understand, you're trying to overwrite the built in function of the Back button? Or you have a Back button on your page?

Comment: Neither (I think). Though if overriding the Back Button is the way to go then I'm all ears. I just want the URL to update as well if I hit the browser back button. Currently, hitting the back button only will only show the previous page/iframe. The URL doesn't change though to reflect that.

Comment: I created a simple test page illustrating the problem on my website. Are we allowed to post external links to personal sites? Sorry, obviously new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may find the popstate event interesting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

First, I would change few lines of code that you have...

```
function updateURLBar(urlInfo) {
    //we can get this stateObj later...
    var stateObj = { 
        foo: "bar",
        url: urlInfo[1]
    };

    //document.getElementById("iframeContent").src = urlInfo[1];

    // see EDIT notes
    changeIframeSrc(document.getElementById("ifameContent"), urlInfo[1]);

    //window.history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 2", urlInfo[0]);
    window.history.pushState(stateObj, "Page 2", urlInfo[0]);
}
```

And then you can add:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    //Remember our state object?
    changeIframeSrc( document.getElementById("iframeContent") ),event.state.url); // see EDIT notes.
};
```

#### EDIT

**The Iframe caveat**

There is a problem with using pushState and changing `iframe` src attributes. If an `iframe` is in the DOM, and you change the `src` attribute, this will add a state to the browsers history stack. Therefore, if you use `history.pushState` with `iframe.src = url`, then you will create 2 history entries.

**The Workaround**

Changing the `src` attribute of an `iframe` element when the `iframe` is not in the DOM will **not** push to the browsers history stack.

Therefore you could build a new `iframe`, set it's `src` attribute, and then replace the old `iframe` with the new one.

```
var changeIframeSrc = function(iframe, src) {
    var frame = iframe.cloneNode();
    frame.src = src;
    iframe.parentNode.replaceChild(frame, iframe);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Norman. I actually tried using pushState before and ran into the same realization of making two entries to the history. I'm also realizing Chrome and Firefox also behave a bit differently in regards to all this. I was hoping to avoid something like workaround you mentioned just because I'm pretty far into development of the site but I'll probably have to go this route if I can't find a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yah I didn't realize that iframes does this myself when I posted my original answer. I couldn't find a better solution myself. Good luck!

Comment: Ended up going this route since I have not been able to figure out another solution. Thanks!

Comment: let me suggest another (perhaps cleaner) workaround: use `frame.contentWindow.location.replace(newUrl)` to navigate the iframe to the new url. This doesn't create a new history state.

Comment: @tato good suggestion! Probably more efficient than the `cloneNode` strategy.