# iframe and Browser back arrow issues

Tags: javascript, iframe, back-button, browser-history

We have an iframe that slides in/out quickly and works fine. EXCEPT after we slide it out and in, the browser back arrow (chrome in this case) no longer works on any URL. What's occurring is the back arrow is scrolling through the iframe's history rather than the parent site/url which makes it seem the back arrow isn't 'working' because the iframe is slid away and not visible.

The current solution we've found is to destroy and recreate the iframe which adds rather considerable time (2-3 seconds) every time we slide it in and out.

Is there a better way to do this (both Chrome and FF ideally) without destroying the iframe?  Note, we are aware of a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859048/updating-an-iframe-history-and-url-then-making-it-work-with-back-button) (possibly related) SO post.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Well I guess you could only try and make the iframe not create a navigation history, by not actually navigating around inside it, but only replacing the current URL.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for your response. Do you have sample code you can share--especially vis-a-vis the SO post I referred to (which seems to be destroying the iFrame as well using replaceChild())